# Where is the Bluth Company model home located?

Tags: arrested-development

In Arrested Development, which is set in Orange County, CA, the model home is shown visibly in a undeveloped area. This area specifically a residential development called Sudden Valley. Where in O.C. is the model home located? From the locations listed on the show the family appears to be somewhere in Irvine or Newport Beach but the location of the model home doesn't seem to be stated on screen.

Comment: I see this as a trivia question, as learning the precise or general location of the model home (it may not be real-- it's a fictional show after all) probably will not improve your understanding of the the show. That said, I'm not downvoting or voting to close, cuz I want to see what other people think first.

Comment: @stevvve (Holt!) There are also no outside shots of the house (the one exception I can think of is when Gob thought he crushed George under the house), otherwise we only see the often reused image of the house in the undeveloped plot. It's very likely that this house wasn't up for the entire length of the show and the same shot was reused.

Answer (score 3):

From the [Arrested Development Wiki](http://arresteddevelopment.wikia.com/wiki/Sudden_Valley#Location):

> A map of Sudden Valley shows its location northeast of Mission Viejo
>   and Las Flores, putting approximately in the location of Rancho Santa
>   Margarita, Orange County, California.